# Gravar erros vindo do Soap-Server

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um client-soap no laravel e gostaria de saber como guardar em um arquivo os erros que voltam do soap-server. Abaixo está o código do meu client-soap e onde faz a requisição pro soap-server.

```
        try {
        print("<pre>".print_r($client->INC($array),true)."</pre>");

        }
        catch (SoapFault $fault){
        echo 'Requesição : <br/><xmp>',
        print_r($client->getLastRequest()),
        '</xmp><br/>';
        echo "</br>";
        echo 'Resposta da ACM : <br/> <br/><xmp>',
        print_r($client->getLastResponse()),
        $fault->faultstring,
        '</xmp>';
    }
```

Eu gostaria de pegar o erro do $fault->faultstring e gravar, como eu faria isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
$conteudo = $fault->faultstring;
Storage::put('logxml.txt', $conteudo);
```

[Referência](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#storing-files)

Este nome é apenas de exemplo, você pode tanto alterar o nome, quanto adicionar pastas antes, quanto alterar a extensão. Segue outro exemplo:

```
$conteudo = $fault->faultstring;
Storage::put('logs-meus/meu-log-xml.xml', $conteudo);
```

Comment: Ok muito obrigado. Deu certo.